# Escaping "<" in JavaScript part of SVG file

Tags: javascript, html, xml, svg

I'm having an issue with using the "<" character in the JavaScript part of my dynamic SVG file.
Opening the file in browser gives me a not well-formed error pointing at the next character.

I realised that I will probably have to escape this character, but I don't know how.
Using `$lt` as recommended for escaping < in XML didn't work.

Here is a little code snippet showing the issue:

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <script>

    for (it=0;it<5;it++) {
      
    }

  <script>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the JS content (e.g., everything after `<script>` should be wrapped in `<![CDATA[`.

E.g.,

```
<svg ...>
  <script><![CDATA[
    ...JS...
  ]]>
  </script>
  ...
</svg>
```

Normal XML stuff.